# ReactJS: how to add a functionality to any React Component by default in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, refactoring, dry

Let say this is how I pass in functions to `MyComponent`:

```js
<MyComponent
  setMyValue={this.setMyValue}
  setYourValue={this.setYourValue}
  updateTheirValues={this.updateTheirValues}
  updateHerValue={this.updateHerValue}
  loadHisValue={this.loadHisValue}

  {...this.props}
/>
```

Is there anyway I can add a functionality - called something like `_passFunctions` to any component in my app to do:

```js
<MyComponent
    __passFunctions={[
      this.loadHisValue,
      this.updateHerValue,
      this.updateTheirValues,
      this.setYourValue,
      this.setMyValue
    ]}
    {...this.props}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object spread in component

**Example**

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div></div>
}

const App = () => {

  const loadHisValue = () => {};
  const updateHerValue = () => {};
  const updateTheirValues = () => {};
  const setYourValue = () => {};
  const setMyValue = () => {};

  const functionalities = {
    loadHisValue,
    updateHerValue,
    updateTheirValues,
    setYourValue,
    setMyValue
    };

  return <div>
    <MyComponent {...functionalities}/>
  </div>
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

> to any component in my app to do:

You can extract functionalities to separate module and use it in every component in a way above or you can follow best practices and use React.Context or Redux

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) from underscore or similar to extract specific keys from an object e.g. like:

```
<MyComponent
  { ..._.pick(
    this,
    'loadHisValue',
    'updateHerValue',
    'updateTheirValues',
    'setYourValue', 
    'setMyValue'
  )}
  {...this.props}
/>
```